# How to remove warning by npm?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

When I run `npm install`, I get the following error:

`npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Here is what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^0.4.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove this error?

Comment: Downgrade that plugin to the 5.x its peer requires, or ignore the warning.

Comment: If I downgrade `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, then I get the following error: `npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@16.1.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Ignoring this warning is not an option.

Comment: Then downgrade *that* plugin until it's happy with the other one. Continue until no warnings, or until you get bored.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, it is a WARNing

1. The easiest trial is delete `node_modules` directory and retype to see if it persists

   ```
   npm install
   ```
2. Moreover you can use [npm-install-peers](https://github.com/spatie/npm-install-peers) to find and install required peer dependencies

   ```
   npm install -g npm-install-peers
   npm-install-peers
   ```
3. Also you can [change the log level](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel) to *error* so that you won't see the warnings